# Change specific nodes shapes based on a list

Tags: python, networkx

Since it is possible to change node color, edgecolor, node size etc of specific nodes within a graph, I was wondering if there's a way to change the shape of specific nodes using a list. I've tried the following code:

```
node_shape = []  
for node in S:
    if node in nodes_of_interest:
        node_shape.append('d')
    else:
        node_shape.append('o')

nx.draw_networkx(S, pos = layout, font_size = '14', node_color = color_map, edgecolors = edge_colors, node_size = node_size,font_weight='bold', )
```

However I receive the following error:

```
ValueError: Unrecognized marker style ['o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'd', 'o', 'o', 'd', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'd', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'd', 'd', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'd', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o', 'o']
```

I was wondering if I made a mistake or if this is just not possible. Thanks for all your suggestions in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nodes are ultimately drawn using matplotlib's [`scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html). This is from the source code for [`nx.draw_network_nodes`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.html#draw_networkx_nodes), which is called from within [`nx.draw_networkx`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/_modules/networkx/drawing/nx_pylab.html#draw_networkx):

```
node_collection = ax.scatter(xy[:, 0], xy[:, 1],
                             s=node_size,
                             c=node_color,
                             marker=node_shape,
                             cmap=cmap,
                             vmin=vmin,
                             vmax=vmax,
                             alpha=alpha,
                             linewidths=linewidths,
                             edgecolors=edgecolors,
                             label=label)
```

But each call to `scatter` will only accept one marker for all points being plotted. Therefore, in order to have different markers you will need to make multiple calls to the plotting function -- one for each subset of nodes having the same marker style. Here's a simple working example:

```py
    G = nx.Graph(np.array([[0,1,0],[1,0,1],[0,1,0]]))
    layout = nx.layout.spring_layout(G)
    nodes_of_interest = [0,2]
    other_nodes = [1]
    nx.draw_networkx(G,layout,nodelist=nodes_of_interest,node_shape='d')
    nx.draw_networkx(G,layout,nodelist=other_nodes,node_shape='o')
```

PS: for fine-tuning, it is oftentimes helpful to use `nx.draw_network_nodes` together with `nx.draw_network_edges` directly, instead of `nx.draw_networkx`.